# Read text file specific string through vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I have text file with multiple line of different jobs jobs status .last run date..etc has been given as below

```
Jobname=FC;lastdate=12032015;lastresult=0
```

I need to write out the `jobname` and `lastresult` status  with "success" for `0` and "fail" for other cases.

Comment: Are you looking for someone to write the vbscript for you, or did you have a particulate question about the script you've written?

Comment: I don't hv script handy..I just not able to find command to match the pattern...I don't need to write script for me...but can give me a clue to do that..

Answer (score 0):

As you iterating through the lines of the file (where `readline` is the variable holding the line we are reading at the time):

```
jobname= Split(Split(readLine, ";")(0), "=")(1)
if Split(Split(readLine, ";")(2), "=")(1) = 0 Then
    lastresult="Success"
else
    lastresult="Failure"
end if
```

Something like this should capture your `jobname` and `lastresult`. We are just using `SPLIT()` to split the string by a delimiter ";" and grabbing the token we need (and then splitting that as well).

Answer (score 0):

Use a Regexp looking for = followed by a sequence of non-; and an array indexed by the comparison between "=0" and the last part of the input line - as in:

```
>> Set r = New RegExp
>> r.Global = True
>> r.Pattern = "=[^;]+"
>> a = Split("success fail")
>> s = "Jobname=FC;lastdate=12032015;lastresult=0|Jobname=Other;lastdate=12032015;lastresult=Else"
>> For Each s In Split(s, "|")
>>     Set ms = r.Execute(s)
>>     WScript.Echo Mid(ms(0).Value,2), a(1 + ("=0" = ms(2)))
>> Next
>>
FC success
Other fail
```